# Para que serve a expressão 'if __name__ == "__main__"'?

Tags: python

Percebo que alguns scripts em `Python`, logo no final do código, possuem a seguinte expressão:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   #faça alguma coisa aqui
```

Qual é o objetivo disso?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`if __name__ == "__main__"` testa se o arquivo de script Python está sendo executado como arquivo principal ou não. Isto é útil para evitar certos comportamentos caso seu script seja importado como módulo de outro script.

Dentro deste `if` normalmente se colocam alguns comportamentos como testes, valores de saída ou funcionalidades especiais.

Para verificar como isto funciona, experimente definir um arquivo `.py` com apenas o seguinte:

```
print(__name__)
```

Salve o arquivo e execute ele como:

```
python meuteste.py
```

A saída deverá ser:

```
__main__
```

Agora, abra o console do Python e importe o arquivo. A saída deverá ser:

```
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct 15 2015, 16:17:59)
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import meuteste
meuteste
>>>
```

Comment: Muito bom, Senhor Cigano. +1

Answer (score 8):

Quando o interpretador `Python` lê um arquivo de origem, ele executa todo o código encontrado nele. Antes de executar o código, ele irá definir algumas `variáveis` ​​especiais. Por exemplo, se o interpretador `Python` está executando esse módulo (o arquivo de origem) como o programa principal, ele define o especial `__name__` para ter um valor `__main__`. Se este arquivo for importado de outro módulo, `__name__` será definido como o nome do outro módulo.

[fonte :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: Só uma correção, na resposta que você linkou diz: `If this file is being imported from another module, __name__ will be set to the module's name.` você interpretou que o `__name__ ` receberá o nome do outro módulo, eu fiquei na dúvida e testei, o resultado é que `__name__` recebe o nome do próprio módulo.

Answer (score 2):

Em termos práticos, todo o código escrito dentro dessa expressão apenas será executado se a biblioteca for usada diretamente, por exemplo, se o ficheiro em questão for executado desta forma:

```
python ficheiro.py
```

O código dentro da expressão será executado. Ao passo que se a biblioteca for importada por outro módulo:

```
import ficheiro
```

O código dentro da expressão não será executado.

Answer (score -5):

`if __main__ == '__name__':
    print(__main__)`

Comment: Ao responder imagine que está escrevendo um documento técnico que objetiva solucionar uma solicitação. Seja claro e explicativo, se possível adicione referências corroborativas ao conteúdo. Leia [answer].