# Como tirar screenshot da tela em Python?

Tags: python

Gostaria de fazer um programa que faça screenshot da tela ( foto da tela) em Python.

Achei o seguinte código:

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # fullscreen
    im=ImageGrab.grab()
    im.show()
```

O código não faz nada (aparentemente fica travado)!

O que significa:  `if __name__ == "__main__":`?

Uso BackBox Linux

Comment: Aqui funcionou. Sobre sua segunda pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92586/no-final-do-c%c3%b3digo-para-que-serve-a-express%c3%a3o-if-name-main

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primeiramente se você não tiver instalado o módulo, [instale](http://pyscreenshot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation):

```
~$ sudo apt-get install python-pip && pip install pyscreenshot
```

<sub>**Obs**: O [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) é uma ferramenta para instalação de módulos do Python.</sub>

Para usar o `pyscreenshot` basta fazer:

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

def main():
    imagem = ImageGrab.grab()
    imagem.save('screenShot1.jpg', 'jpeg')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

O código acima vai gerar uma imagem `JPEG` e salvá-la como *screenShot1.jpg* no mesmo diretório do *script*.

A tua segunda pergunta é [respondida **aqui**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92586/6454).

Comment: Eu já tinha tudo instalado aqui mas mesmo assim o código continua não fazendo nada (parece estar em loop)... Usei python 3.4 no linux BackBox. Tentei rodar no python 2.7 mas : "ImportError: No module named pyscreenshot" mesmo dando o pip install.

Comment: aparentemente  o pip instalou o pyscreenshot apenas para o python 3. Como fazer o mesmo para o python 2.7?

Comment: pip 7.1.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)

Comment: Este código só funciona no python 2?

Comment: @EdS Instale o `pyscreenshot` no Python 2 assim: `sudo pip2 install pyscreenshot`. Veja se funciona!

Comment: # sudo pip2 install pyscreenshot
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyscreenshot in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): EasyProcess in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pyscreenshot)

Comment: Eu executo o código mas ele não faz nada e não dá erros! Parece estar em loop. Que estranho!

Comment: @EdS Você está executando o *script* assim: `python2 nomeScript.py`? depois de executar o *script* veja se um arquivo **screenShot1.jpg** aparece na mesma pasta do *script*!

Comment: Não. Eu estava executando com o IDLE do Python 2.7.6. Pela linha de comando python2 nomeScript.py FUNCIONOU! Não consigo entender a diferença!

Comment: python3 screenshot.py também funcionou. Alguma ideia de porque pelo IDLE fica em loop? Que coisa estranha!

Comment: @EdS Também não sei, talvez o IDLE adicione algum parâmetro ao executar o *script* ou algo assim.