# Importando valores de outros códigos no tkinter - python

Tags: python, tkinter, biblioteca

Olá, estou fazendo um programa grande e queria dividir as telas em outros códigos, já consigo importar as telas, mas preciso pegar alguns valores de outras telas, porem não consigo fazer isso.

## Primeira tela:

```
from tkinter import *
import teste_interface2
def teste():
    teste_interface2.tela_teste()

def tela():
    janela = Tk()
    janela.geometry("300x300+300+300")
    lb1 = Label(janela, text = "Insira letras,testando a exportação:").pack()
    global ed1_interface1
    ed1_interface1 = Entry(janela).pack()
    bt = Button(janela, text = "exportar", command = teste).pack()

tela()
```

## Segunda tela

```
from tkinter import*
import teste_interface1

def importacao():
    teste_import = ed1_interface1.get()
    lb = Label(janela1, text = teste_import).pack()

def tela_teste():
    global janela1
    janela1 =  Tk()
    janela1.geometry("300x300+300+300")
    bt1 = Button(janela1, text = "importar", command = importacao).pack()
```

É possível fazer essa exportação/importação ou é mais fácil deixar tudo num arquivo só? Obrigado

Comment: O que exatamente você quer importar, @AntonioGally? Uma função, uma variável, etc

Comment: Quero exportar o valor de uma variável

Answer (score 0):

Com base no seu código de exemplo uma das possibilidades seria:

### Primeira tela:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""teste_interface1.py"""
import tkinter as tk

import teste_interface2


def abrir_tela_2(instance, widget):
    valor = widget.get()
    instance.destroy()
    teste_interface2.tela2(valor)


def tela1(entry=None):
    janela = tk.Tk()
    janela.geometry("300x300+300+300")
    janela.title('Teste interface 1')

    valor_entry_interface2 = "Valor que estava no Entry da tela 1: %s" % entry
    if entry is None:
        valor_entry_interface2 = "Bem vindo"

    label = tk.Label(janela, text=valor_entry_interface2)
    label.pack()

    label_interface1 = tk.Label(janela, text="Insira letras,testando a exportação:")
    label_interface1.pack()

    entry_interface1 = tk.Entry(janela)
    entry_interface1.pack()

    button_interface1 = tk.Button(janela, text="exportar",
                                  command=lambda: abrir_tela_2(instance=janela, widget=entry_interface1))
    button_interface1.pack()

    janela.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tela1()
```

### Segunda tela:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""teste_interface2.py"""
import tkinter as tk

import teste_interface1


def abrir_tela_1(instance, widget):
    valor = widget.get()
    instance.destroy()
    teste_interface1.tela1(valor)


def tela2(entry=None):
    janela = tk.Tk()
    janela.geometry("300x300+300+300")
    janela.title('Teste interface 2')

    valor_entry_interface1 = "Valor que estava no Entry da tela 1: %s" % entry
    if entry is None:
        valor_entry_interface1 = "Bem vindo"

    label = tk.Label(janela, text=valor_entry_interface1)
    label.pack()

    label_interface2 = tk.Label(janela, text="Insira letras,testando a exportação:")
    label_interface2.pack()

    entry_interface2 = tk.Entry(janela)
    entry_interface2.pack()

    button_interface2 = tk.Button(janela, text="exportar",
                                  command=lambda: abrir_tela_1(instance=janela, widget=entry_interface2))
    button_interface2.pack()

    janela.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tela2()
```

Deixar em um único arquivos ou separar em vários irá depender do que fica mais simples para você dar manutenção ou mesmo do **tamanho** do projeto.

A unica questão que demanda um pouco mais de cuidado é ao se trabalhar com arquivos/scripts que serão importados, pois você deve utilizar `if __name__ == '__main__':` para **"separar"** a execução **local** do arquivo da **importação**:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/92589/93029